# Replacing one XML element with another

Tags: shell

I'm interested in finding out what's the shortest script one can write to replace one XML element in a file with another one from a second file.

I can whip up a simple program to easily do this, but I'm wondering if it's easily do-able using a shell script. It's just a utility tool meant as a convenience. Can this be done using `sed`? `awk`? I'm not familiar with those. I suppose I can probably do it with a combination of `grep` and `wc`, but it seems likely that there's a much more direct way to do this.

Essentially, I have a large configuration file, say `config.xml`, which say looks like this:

```
<config>
    <element name="a">
        <subelement />
    </element>
    <element name="b">
        <subelement />
    </element>
    <element name="c">
        <subelement />
    </element>
    <!-- and so on... -->
</config>
```

Once in a while, changes require me to modify/add/delete one `subelement`. Now, it so happens that there's a sort of generator that will generate an up-to-date `subconfig.xml`, like following  file:

```
<config>
    <element name="c">
        <subelement />
        <subelement />
    </element>
</config>
```

My thinking is that if I can take the `element` in `subconfig.xml` and replace the existing one in `config.xml`, then hey, that'd be great! Yea, it's not much a work-saver, since it's only needed rarely, but it just occurred to me that I could try to do it in a script, but I'm not sure how.

Any help appreciated (including pointing out that I'd be better off writing a program for this ^-^).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your xml are consistent and your replacement requirement is simple, there's actually no need to use parsers. Just simple awk will do

```
$ subconfig=(<subconfig.xml)
$ awk -v subconf=$subconfig '/<config>/{print subconf}/<config>/,/<\/config>/{next}1' config.xml
```

Comment: I ended up using a combination of awk to get the line numbers and then manipulated it using head, and tail. The script you provided didn't work in shell, so I just kept playing around with it until I got it to work. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't attempt to do this with command-line tools, you'll run into all sorts of difficulties. The way you should do this is with a proper XML parser. The logic would be: consume original file, parse it, consume update file, parse it, identify which node this guy is to replace, do the replace, write out the result.

I don't know what you are comfortable with coding-wise, but there's XML parsers available in most popular languages.

Comment: Yep, I know it's easily done with an XML library, but I'm just using it as a personal convenience script, so I don't want to bother with an application :)